# Can I use jumper cables to display my LEDs far away from the breadboard?

Tags: led, connector, breadboard

Apologies for a possible very newbie question.

I would like to create a small circuit using a breadboard and a 6V power source.
My goal is to have 10 LEDs running in parallel (each with its own resistor). So far so good : I have watched some tutorials and it seems to work on my end.

However, all the tutorials show the LEDs planted directly on the breadboard. I need them to be up to 50 cm away from the breadboard, and I'm not sure how to connect the LEDs with the breadboard.

My attempt so far has been to put each leg of an LED into the female end of a [male-female jumper cable](https://phi-education.com/store/image/cache/data/electronics/cables_wires_connectors/male_female_wire_strip/main-750x500.png), but since the LED leg is thinner than the hole I tape them together with electrical tape so that they stay bound together, which sounds sub-optimal but works.

I have seen [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/122827/272461) that suggests an insulated hookup wire but it sounds overkill, at least in my newbie eyes : all I seem to need is a jumper cable but with a narrower connector. Is my reasoning correct?
If so (and if not as well), what cable can help me display the LEDs away from the breadboard without using tape?

Comment: Why not just use plain old wires and solder them to the LED? I don't like those cheap uncontrolled soldering irons but they'll do the job for something like this.

Comment: Re, "overkill." If it gets the job done, and if it's not expensive, then that should be the end of the story. It's not "overkill" unless it's over-budget

Comment: I suspect that Bruno doesn't have a soldering iron. Is that right?

Comment: @user253751 I'd assume they don't, but I'm pretty sure you can get a cheap piece-of-junk iron from a home improvement store for like $5, so that may still be an option. (though I'd recommend getting a proper good iron if you want to get into electronics!)

Comment: LEDs are fine.. If I was being lazy I would do what you do and stick the LED leads into the end of a female jumper. I'd pick LEDs with thicker leads so that I wouldn't have to fold them over to make them wide enough to hold in the jumper.

Comment: You can bend a wave into the LED leads so they'll "stick" into the jumper cable female end -- but it'll only last for a while.  It's much better to properly connect the hook-up wire to the LED leads, with solder and heat-shrink tubing for insulation.

Comment: @user253751 That's correct. I was hoping that I could get the job done by just clipping things together :-) Hearth : I didn't think that soldering irons could be that cheap but you are right, then can be. I will consider it, even though a downside is that I will have to deal with insulation. DKNguyen : That would be ideal, but I didn't find LEDs with legs that have the same thickness as the jumper cable

Comment: @BrunoPérel I don't know how expensive things are in your country, but if you will be doing lots of electronics work and can afford it, then you do want a good soldering iron with temperature control. For insulation, buy heat-shrink tubing (or just "heatshrink" for short). You can put it over the wire before you solder, then after you solder, slide it into the right place, and heat it up to seal it in place. (You can heat it with a cigarette lighter, or by holding the soldering iron underneath it. It doesn't need very much heat)